# Confused about optional chaining in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

This is my code:

```
type State = {
  foo: Foo | null
}

type Foo = {
  bar: number
}

function A (state: State) {
  const bar = state.foo?.bar

  if (!bar) return 

  state.foo  // foo: Foo | null
}
```

Can someone tell me how state.foo can be null at the bottom of the function? Thanks! :)

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/FAFwngDgpgBAyiAhiWBeGBvYMYDMD2+AXDAGKEwA+MAdgK4A2DwAvsKJLOfjOljgCNEAJxL0AtgKjDW7XHRoBjEAEt8NGAEEYACgDOSFCQTIoASkzYYi9QZhDhvGAdMA6AvgD8rh+xwrcXQBCBwthKBA6YQ0-Z0Mod0JZIA

Comment: TS does not track references when narrowing down a type. So if you have `if (!a) return; a++`  for example, that would work but `b = a; if(!b) return; a++` would not work because TS would have to track that `b` is `a`.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot! I need both foo and bar to be truthy in order to continue. How can I write the guard statement most elegantly then? :)

Comment: @mspoulsen change `if (!bar) return` to `if (!state.foo) return`. It would work

Comment: No, because then bar can be falsy...We can obviously write `if (!state.foo || !bar) return`. I was just looking for a cleaner way...

Comment: "*I need both foo and bar to be truthy in order to continue.*" then why not `if (!state.foo || !bar) return;` or `if (state.foo && bar) return;`? It's very slightly redundant but expresses exactly what you said. And the redundancy is hardly a problem.

Comment: I will. Was just hoping the optional chaining could express it more elegantly. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @mspoulsen "*I will. Was just hoping the optional chaining could express it more elegantly.*" it does, however TS doesn't take it into account. If `foo` is nullish, then `bar` is always nullish, as well. If `bar` is *not* nullish, then `foo` cannot be nullish. The logic stands. However, the `if` that makes it explicit is not really much worse, either.

Comment: But shouldn't TS take it into account? I mean bar will always be falsy here if foo is falsy. Do you know why TS does not infer this?